# bash traps: letting command finish before ctrl+c is processed

Tags: bash

trap should be executed after the currently running command is finished, but in the following example upon pressing Ctrl+C it interrupts the current command (sleep) before the 10 seconds are over , prints the message "SIGINT received" and then immediately starts the next sleep:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'echo SIGINT received' INT

counter=0
while true
   do
   let counter=counter+1
   echo start sleeping period $counter
   sleep 10
done
```

Is there anything wrong with my use of trap? How can I achieve a behaviour that lets the current command finish after pressing Ctrl+C, without using a child process or subshell (this way is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18683439/5612244))?

Comment: Traps (and signal handlers in general) have lots of behaviors; it's helpful to pick a question title that gives (potential) readers an idea of just which ones you're asking about. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ctrl+C interrupts the current foreground group, which in your case is both the script itself and sleep.

Since `sleep` dies on SIGINT, it exits immediately. This causes the message to be printed immediately.

If you want to be able to send a SIGINT to your process without it dying, you can ignore the signal before starting the process and hope that the process doesn't reset the signal action (most programs don't):

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'echo SIGINT received' INT

counter=0
while true
   do
   let counter=counter+1
   echo "start sleeping period $counter"
   ( trap '' INT; exec sleep 10; )
done
```

Comment: How can I get a behaviour that gives me the desired behaviour when pressing Ctrl+C (waiting for the current command to finish)? See updated Question.

Comment: Press the "See updated answer" button to see the latest version of the answer, which includes this.

Comment: If I have to hope the signal action isn't reset does this mean it could sometimes work and sometimes not?

Comment: It will work for commands that don't try to handle their own signals. `sleep` doesn't, so it works. `ping` does, so it fails.